# How to setValue of textfield in Dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to store text of UITextField in dictionary and want to update that text in label.But i don't  know how to do it.How to define key etc.

```
[self.dataDictionory setValue:textfld.text forKey:@"myValues"];
```

here is my code which i am trying but app crashes.I know this is wrong code.Then how can i set the value in dictionary.

Comment: Whenever you post a question about code that crashes, always include details about the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make sure that the NSDictionary is `NSMutableDictionary`

```
self.dataDictionory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[self.dataDictionory setValue:textfld.text forKey:@"myValues"];
```

Comment: ,One more thing,how to set this value in my label.